# Examples of spaces where the distance of closed subsets doesn't work

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this question:

Given the following distance between $2$ subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$:

$$ d\left(S_{1}, S_{2}\right)=\inf \left\{d(x, y): x \in S_{1}, y \in S_{2}\right\}.$$

Show by example that if $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are closed but not compact, is not always true that $d\left(S_{1}, S_{2}\right)=d(x, y)$ for some $x \in S_{1}$ $y \in S_{2}$.

My imagination doesn't go far enough from $R^n$, so I am having troubles thinking on a example of this characteristics, I am thinking that maybe a stranger space can work, but I don't know many, if you can give me some space where this could happen it will be very usefull. Thanks

Comment: You can do it in $\Bbb R^2$. HINT: One of the sets can be the graph of a function that has an asymptote.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oooohhh how coudn't I see it, thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $S_1=\{(0,y)\ |\ y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $S_2=\{(x,1/x)\ |\ x\in(0,\infty)\}$. Note that both are closed, $d(S_1,S_2)=0$ but they are disjoint and so $d(v,w)>0$ for any $v\in S_1$ and $w\in S_2$.

Answer (score 1):

In $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ the sets $A = [-1,0)$ and $B= (0,1]$ are closed and bounded (*not* compact, though) and $d(A,B)=0$ (as witnessed by $d(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \to 0$) but there is no $a \in A, b \in B$ with $d(a,b)=0$ as the sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.